# Saving a SQL query and retrieving data from last query result

Tags: java, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm designing a database and a Java application to the following:
1. Allow user to query the database via an API.
2. Allow a user to save a query and identify the query via a 'query-id'. User can then pass-in 'query-id' on next call to API, which will execute the query associated with id but it will only retrieve data from the last time the specific query was requested.
    - Along with this, I would also need to save the query-id information for each UserID.

Information regarding the Database
The database of choice is PostgreSQL and the information to be requested by user will be stored in various tables.

**My question:** Any suggestions/advice/tips on how to go about implementing requirement 
No. 2?
Is there an existing design pattern, sql queries, built-in db function on how to save a query and fetch information from multiple tables from the last returned results.

Note:
My initial thoughts so far is to store the last row(each row in all the tables will have a primary key) read from each table into a data structure and then save this data structure for each saved query and use it when retrieving data again.

For storing the user and query-id information, I was thinking of creating a separate table to store the UserName, UserUUID, SavedQuery, LastInfoRetrieved.

Thanks.

Comment: A pretty straightforward solution to #2 would be to save the last result in the table with the query and query-id, when you see the query-id return the previous results then overwrite them with the new query

Comment: @HunterMcMillen When the query-id is present on the api call it means user wants to execute their saved query and return data from last time it left off. Saving the last query results And returning is not what I want to do. I hope I clarified this well.

Comment: how complex can your query become? your outline suggests that each result set would consist of a single record only at most, is that correct? if it is, build a set of 3 tables (simplified notation) `user(uuid pk, name, sqid fk)`, `savedquery ( sqid pk, querydesc )` and `result ( uuid fk, valid, pk_table1 fk nullable, pk_table2 fk nullable, ...)`. this assumes that users may only retrieve their latest query results. `valid` caters for the case that data is deleted from the database which has been part of saved query results. deletion code will be needed to update the affected `pk_table` fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a question.  The obvious tool to use here would prepared statements but since these are planned on first run, they can run into problems when run multiple times with multiple parameters.  Consider the difference, assuming that id ranges from 1 to 1000000 between:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id > 999900;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id > 10;
```

The first should use an index while the second should do a physical-order scan of the table.

A second possibility would be to have functions which [return refcursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).  This would mean the query is actually run when the refcursor is returned.

A third possibility would be to have a schema of tables that could be used for this, per session, holding results.  Ideally these would be temporary tables in pg_temp, but if you have to preserve across sessions, that may be less desirable.  Building such a solution is a lot more work and adds a lot of complexity (read: *things that can go wrong*) so it is really a last choice.

From what you say, refcursors sound like the way to do this but keep in mind PostgreSQL needs to know what data types to return so you can run into some difficulties in this regard (read the documentation thoroughly before proceeding), and if prepared statements gets where you need to go, that might be simpler.